# Changing position from static to relative makes absolute span disappear

Tags: html, css

I am having two different spans in my page, one with `absolute` position and the other with `relative` position.  Plunker code is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/RT563vhLBaWnITqr9xnY?p=preview).

Now, I see the absolute positioned div is completely hidden as,

[image]

But when i change my `relative`-ly positioned span to `static` position, the `absolute` position span comes to the top as,

[image]

[css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/) says,

> If you set `position: relative`; on an element but no other positioning
>   attributes (`top`, `left`, `bottom` or `right`), it will no effect on it's
>   positioning at all, it will be exactly as it would be if you left it
>   as `position: static;`

As i can see, both `relative` and `static` are not same. How does `relative` and `static` position affect what is displayed over the top layer?

Answer (score 2):

You have **absolute** div present in view, its just u wrote the span with absolute class after span with relative class, so the green block is coming on top of black one. if u give `z-index:2;` for absolute class then u can see the absolute class span